# No sequence of points in a string

Tags: regex

I used the following condition de validate a string param

```
    if (!empty($value) && !preg_match("/^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿĀ-ž\s\'\.\-]+$/", $value, $matches)) {
        echo "KO";
    }
echo "OK";
```

I'd like that this REGEX does not accept a string like : **"tes....t"**,  **"...example"**

=> that is to say don't accept a **sequence of points**

So waht can i do ?

Comment: You could add a negative lookahead `^(?!.*\.\.)[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿĀ-ž\s'.-]+$` or repeat the character class preceded by the dot `^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿĀ-ž\s'-]+(?:\.[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿĀ-ž\s'-]+)*$`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but your regex does not accept a simple string like "test" for exemple

Comment: I forgot a quantifier, this should work `^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿĀ-ž\s'-]+(?:\.[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿĀ-ž\s'-]+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/aHS5Rd/1

Comment: thx a lot , you can put  it as an answer to validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take out the dot from the character class, and optionally repeat it prepending the dot.

```
^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿĀ-ž\s'-]+(?:\.[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿĀ-ž\s'-]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aHS5Rd/1)

Another option is to use a negative lookahead to rule out 2 consecutive dots.

```
^(?!.*\.\.)[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿĀ-ž\s'.-]+$
```

The pattern does contain `\s` which could possibly also match a newline. If you want to match horizontal whitespace chars, you could change it to `\h`

I would suggest using an else clause to test it, to prevent always echo `"OK"`

```
$value = "test..";
if (!empty($value) && !preg_match("/^(?!.*\.\.)[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿĀ-ž\s'.-]+$/", $value, $matches)) {
    echo "KO";
} else {
    echo "OK";
}
```

Output

```
KO
```